# How can I sign a Firefox WebExtension without using the web-ext tool?

Tags: firefox, npm, firefox-addon-webextensions

To build/sign WebExtensions, Mozilla suggests the [web-ext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Getting_started_with_web-ext) CLI tool:

> web-ext is a node-based application that you can install with the [nodejs/npm](https://nodejs.org/) tool.

From the Mozdev [distribution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution) article (bolding is mine):

> Only Mozilla can sign your add-on so that Firefox will install it by default. Add-ons are signed by [submitting them to AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org/developers/addon/submit) **or using the API** and passing either an automated or manual code review.

If I'd rather not have node/npm on my development box, **how can I sign my WebExtension without using web-ext?**

Comment: You have quite a few questions. Most/all of these are already answered in other questions, in one form or another. I would suggest you search around a bit.

Comment: Given that the MDN documentation page which you linked to has a *direct link* in it's [Signing API section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution#Signing_API) to a [Mozilla page which provides you with *explicit examples*, **using `curl`**,](http://addons-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/api/signing.html) of how to do what you want, you have *clearly* not done enough research.

Comment: @Makyen I've changed the title and the question (bolded). Is that better?

Comment: @Makyen I didn't follow that link because it seemed to be about old-style addons (rather than webextensions). Perhaps that's a misunderstanding that I have about XPI vs webextension terminology. In either case, that does appear to be the answer I'm looking for. I couldn't see a stackoverflow question pointing out that article. If you add an answer mentioning that I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I never use any such tools (not for webext nor for SDK/JPM).

I always develop on my own computer with a text editor, so to answer your question, no, it is not necessary to use such tools.

AFA signing, you will then have to do it manually by visiting AMO, and uploading the add-on as Unlisted. In fact, I think the tool does the same (uploads to AMO and gets a signed response).

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you sign webextensions on AMO without web-ext ? i.e: `can the signing API in fact be used without the web-ext tool`

Comment: @David-SkyMesh .. Added extra notes to the above post regarding the signing.